# dynamically setting kendo window title and content in angular then open window when a button on the form is clicked

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

Here's the basic scenario:  next to some of my form fields, I have a little button with a question mark image. If the user clicks on the button, I want to display a help message for that particular field, using kendo window. I want to set the title of the modal window to the relevant form fieldname, and to set the  window content with a help message for that field.

Code below is from the example I'd like to build on: http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/#/Window

If you notice in the `ng-click` event of the button, the `open()` method of the kendo-window is being invoked. But the title is statically set with `k-title`.  I have changed that to point to scope variables.

I need to invoke a function in my Controller, which will change the `$scope.helpTitle` and `$scope.helpContent` based on which form field the user is asking about, and then open the kendo window.

**What is "the Angular way" to *dynamically* set the title and content of the kendo modal window based on which field the user is asking for help on and then open the window?**

I already have the help content in a local object; no need to fetch it via Ajax.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div style="position: relative; width: 400px; height: 100px">

    <button id="ExpirationDateHelp" class="k-button" ng-show="!win2visible" ng-click="win2.open()">help</button>


    <div kendo-window="win2" k-title="helpTitle"
         k-width="600" k-height="200" k-visible="false"
         k-content="{template:   helpContent }"
         k-on-open="win2visible = true" k-on-close="win2visible = false"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following:

notice that the minute you worte k-window="win2" a scope variable was created referencing this window.

```
$scope.DlgOptions = {
            modal: true,
            title: "My Dyanamic Title",
            width: 1080,
            visible: false,
            draggable: false,
            pinned: true,
            resizable: false
        };

        $scope.win2.setOptions($scope.splashDlgOptions);
        $scope.win2.center();
        $scope.win2.open();
```

Comment: can you please mark this answer with V so everyone would know it's the solution

Comment: I use kendo's official http://dojo.telerik.com/OzuZI ,
and add a line to the controller, console.log($scope.win); I got undefined for $scope.win, how can I use setOptions to an undefined window object? I may not make my point clear, please open the url, open chrome console, then run it and see result.